# Grease pencil depth order changes when rendering animation

Tags: rendering, animation, grease-pencil

In the file, scrubbing through the timeline makes the GP objects to change depth. Changing the viewport shading fixes it. Not so bad.

The problem is when I want to render animation, the problem shows up again. The faulty frames make one character overlap the other. When I render the same frame as single image the render is fine. To clarify, I want to control the depth sorting by spacing the model in 3D, in this case I want only the arm to be on top of the character.

One thing that seems to fix it is setting one character stroke depth to 3D world. Problem being i have like 40 layers and this makes the character a mess.

Z pass seems to have no difference.

Anything that outright solves this is greatly apreciated. But if the characters need to be changed so be it.

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qZViJAUJy17d9XA1c2M0UhWexvWVxl1o/view?usp=sharing)

Duplicate as I don't have time for merging accounts.

Additional info: Problem I have is on blender 3.2, but switching to 3.0 has made the viewport stable. The grease pencil displays correctly in viewport, but animation render still has this issue.
This leads me to belive that it might be a bug.

Comment: Hello and welcome! ...Now which question is the duplicate of which other question? One of them will be closed.

Comment: This one I have have access to. So the other one can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://youtu.be/VE1IRA-OgcQ) have given me a workaround.

Dividing the characters limbs into several grease pencil objects have helped with the problem.
Grease plencil objects draw depth is determined by their origins so moving the limb objects in 3D to correspond with their depth in the 2D space fixes the issue. As previously, multiple layers on different depths and 3D locations shared the same origin point.

The viewport is no longer buggy and rendering animation gives no issues.

Will report back if problems appear.

Comment: Issue still pops up from time to time. Dividing the characters helped, but not solved the issue.